# Angular ng-dirty not toggling with datepicker directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom directive for applying jQuery UI Datepicker to some inputs. I can pick a date and it updates the input. However, when i post back the results. The input(control) that was edited isn't marked dirty so the changes never get saved. See below..

```
     <td>
         <input type="text" jqdatepicker name="Delegation.StartDate" ng-model="delegation.StartDate" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" jqdatepicker name="Delegation.EndDate" ng-model="delegation.EndDate" />
      </td>

App.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'm/dd/yy',
            onSelect: function (date) {
                scope.date = date;
                scope.$apply();
                ngModelCtrl.$setDirty(); <--doesn't work
            }
        });
    }
};});
```

I have tried using scope, element, ngModel and can't get the state of the control to change from pristine to dirty. On save, i scrap the rows(tr) for those that have the class ng-dirty and process them. Any thoughts on how to do this? I use the same method on about 8 other pages without issue but those do not use the directive/datepickers.

Comment: Well... you could always use [angular-ui datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) ?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the update inside `scope.$apply()`? That is, `scope.$apply(function() { scope.date = date; });`.

Comment: Nope still didn't update it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error and reading. I finally got it to work! Below is the directive.

```
App.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'm/dd/yy',
            onSelect: function (date) {
                console.log(ngModelCtrl);
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});